# issue passing the angularJS model value on to bootstrap pop-over. Getting "Undefined" value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to angularjs.  I am trying to show angular model value on to bootstrap popover but the value Its showing is "Undefined"

I have issue passing the angularJs model value on to bootstrap pop-over. this is the code I have in controller page (cshtml)

```
<span custom-popover ng-model= "DetailsData.detailInfo" popover-html="{{DetailsData.detailInfo}}" popover-placement="bottom" popover-label="Label"></span>
```

and I have this below code in controller js file

```
self.GetDetails = function () {
            $http.post("/api/GetDetails", $scope.DetailId).success(function (data) {
                self.safeData = data;
                $scope.DetailsData = self.safeData.Detail;
                $scope.DetailsData.detailInfo = $scope.DetailsData.UPDATED_BY + "," + $scope.DetailsData.UPDATED_DATE;
                $scope.GetAddrDetail('R');
            }).error(function (e) { console.log(e); });
        }
```

and I have this directive created

```
App.directive('customPopover', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'AE',
            scope:false,
            scope: {
                ngModel: '='
            },
            template: '<button type="button" class="btn btn-info">{{label}}</button>',
            replace: true, link: function ($scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
                var string = attr.popoverHtml.split(",");
                console.log($scope);
                console.log($scope.ngModel);
                $scope.label = attr.popoverLabel;
                $(elem).popover({
                    trigger: 'click',
                    html: true,
                    content: '<b>id : </b>' + string[0] + '<br/> <b>datetime : </b>' + string[1],
                    placement: attr.popoverPlacement, title: 'Details',
                    template: '<div class="popover" role="tooltip"><div class="arrow"></div><h3 class="popover-title"></h3><div class="popover-content"></div></div>'
                });
            }
        };
    });
```

//I even tried like this -

also I tried using text input and value was showing fine in  this text box. I am able to get value on to controller and use in a text box but not in popover

```
 <input type="text" ng-model="DetailsData.detailInfo" />
```

When I click on pop over button it shows the pop over title as details and id as blank and datetime: undefined. Could some one please help me where I am doing wrong ? I want to get scope.DetailsData.UPDATED_BY value next to Id: and $scope.DetailsData.UPDATED_DATE value next to datetime: on pop over. Thanks.

Comment: I have even tried like this but no luck.

Comment: <span custom-popover ng-model= "DetailsData.detailInfo" popover-html="{{DetailsData.UPDATED_BY}},{{DetailsData.UPDATED_DATE}}"" popover-placement="bottom" popover-label="Label"></span>

Comment: Try {{DetailsData.UPDATED_BY +','+DetailsData.UPDATED_DATE}}